# Pygame image is not moving properly when using the right code for it

Tags: python, pygame

This is my code for my pygame space invaders.  Right now, I am trying to get the spaceship image to move.  This is my code for it

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1600, 900), pygame.RESIZABLE)

window_width, window_height = screen.get_width(), screen.get_height()

pygame.display.set_caption("space invaders")

icon = pygame.image.load('images/space-invaders.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

player_image = pygame.image.load('images/player.png')
playerX = window_width / 2 - 50
playerY = (window_height / 2) + (window_height / 3)


def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(player_image, (x, y))


running = True
while running:

    playerX_change = 0

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        #if keystroke is pressed check whether its right or left
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                 playerX_change = -5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                 playerX_change = 5

    playerX += playerX_change
    player(playerX, playerY)
```

When I run this code, the spaceship moves every time I click the arrow keys.  But when I hold them, it moves 5 left or right once and then does not move anymore.  How can I fix this.

Comment: Is this exactly how your code is formatted? Because it shouldn't even be working due to the indentation of `if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT`

Comment: no, it is just a formatting issue from StackOverflow I will change it now

Comment: you have mix of two different method of work with keys - `events` and `pygame.key`. If you put `playerX_change = 0` before `while running` then it will move but you will need to check `pygame.KEYUP` to stop it.

Comment: Yeah that fixed it, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mix two different methods - `events` and `pygame.key.get_pressed()`

System sends only one event when you press button so you set `playerX_change = -5` only once and you can't set `playerX_change = 0` inside `loop`. But you will have to also use `event.type == pygame.KEYUP` to stop moving it.

```
# set start value before loop
playerX_change = 0

running = True
while running:

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        #if keystroke is pressed check whether its right or left
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            # set "speed" 
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                 playerX_change = -5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                 playerX_change = 5

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            # reset "speed"
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                 playerX_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                 playerX_change = 0

    playerX += playerX_change
    player(playerX, playerY)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Using `pygame.key.get_pressed()` you can check key in every loop and then you have to set  `playerX_change = 0` before every check.

```
running = True
while running:

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    playerX_change = 0

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
         playerX_change = -5
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
         playerX_change = 5

    playerX += playerX_change
    player(playerX, playerY)

    pygame.display.flip()
```